# Adwords tracking conversions recorded time details

Tags: google-ads-api

I need to check all conversions recorded time from google adwords account.
For example,

if i have totally 3 conversions in all conversions column i need those 3 recorded exact time.

Is that possible to get from our account ?
And is repeat rate will affect the count in all conversions column.
Please help me to check these details

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it's not possible to see/import that into Google Adwords. However, this should be doable in Google Analytics, if you use Transactions and have your own report with multiple dimensions.

[See this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/YV6dHArnklk).

[And this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=time).